# Spring-Security Authorization Roles are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to implement Spring Security based role authorizations in my existing Spring Boot system. I want to restrict access of REST API's as per some user authorizations.

For that I created an SpringConfiguration.java class as below:

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
public class SecurityConfig_BasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   private static String REALM = "Test";

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Deb").password("deb@123").roles("ADMIN"); // Line 1
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Bob").password("Bob@123").roles("USER"); // Line 2
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/checkRoleBaseAuthorization/**")
      .hasRole("ADMIN").and() // Line 3
      .httpBasic().realmName(REALM)
      .authenticationEntryPoint(getBasicAuthEntryPoint()).and()
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
   }

   @Bean
   public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint() {
      return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
   }
}
```

In the above class, I have defined two users/passwords with authorization roles ADMIN/USER. Now I want to allow only those users that have ADMIN roles.

In case credentials do not match below class will return status 401.

**CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java**

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

   @Override
   public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException authException)
         throws IOException, ServletException {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
      response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=" + getRealmName() + "");

      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      writer.println("HTTP Status 401 : " + authException.getMessage());
   }

   @Override
   public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      setRealmName("Test");
      super.afterPropertiesSet();
   }
}
```

**REST API**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/checkRoleBaseAuthorization", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String checkRoleBaseAuthorization() {
      return "checkRoleBaseAuthorization() Invoked";
   }
```

My program is working to an extent i.e. without users/passwords the API is not accessible.

> But why I'm able to login with Bob/Bob@123 too? It has role "USER",
>   not "ADMIN" which I have specified in SecurityConfiguration.java (see
>   line 3).

Comment: Maybe it sounds stupid, but could it be a wrong pattern, what if you try
`antMatchers("/checkRoleBaseAuthorization**")` ?

Comment: Didn't work. If that was the reason I think It wouldn't have worked for Deb either.

Comment: I throw together a quick sample project with two integration tests: one for user with role admin and one for role user. Test with role user receives a HTTP status 403. Are you doing anything else outside of what you've included in the question?